# Query to extract all SQL database roles with INSERT and/or UPDATE privileges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've taken over the support for a SQL 2008 database and there are a multitude of custom roles (25+) associated within. I'm trying to figure out which of the custom roles have the ability to perform privileged INSERT and/or UPDATE actions within the database.

Can anyone help me write a query to run against the database which would return a listing of all roles with INSERT and UPDATE privileges?

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to treat insert/update permissions for a single table/column the same as for a schema, the entire database, db_datawriter, etc.?

Comment: I've used a version of this script by S. Kausen for several years now.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Security/71562/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a starting point.  The first query will give you a list of roles with either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` permission.  From there you will need to look at the permissions being at the `DATABASE`, `SCHEMA`, or `OBJECT` level and decide if they cover the objects you are interested in.  Check the `state_desc` column to make sure it is `GRANT` (it probably will be) as `DENYs` are obviously the opposite of what you want.

The second query will tell you any role that is a member of the `db_datawriter` role.  These roles will also have `INSERT` and `UPDATE` permissions.

```
SELECT dprin.name, dperm.* 
FROM sys.database_permissions dperm
JOIN sys.database_principals dprin
    ON dperm.grantor_principal_id = dprin.principal_id
WHERE permission_name IN ('INSERT','UPDATE')
  AND dprin.type = 'R'

SELECT drole.name as role_name, dprin.name as role_member
FROM sys.database_role_members rmem
JOIN sys.database_principals drole
    ON drole.principal_id = rmem.role_principal_id 
JOIN sys.database_principals dprin
    ON dprin.principal_id = rmem.member_principal_id 
WHERE drole.name = 'db_datawriter'
  AND dprin.type = 'R'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Kenneth Fisher's scripts to identify which roles have these rights.  I assume once you identify the roles in question, you want to get a better idea of what they're doing.  To script them out, feel free to use a script I put together, [here](https://dbaeyes.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/fully-script-out-a-mssql-database-role), which will fully script out the database role definition.